# Flask SSL receiving garbage requests

Tags: python, ssl, flask, https

I've got a basic Flask server setup with some endpoints. I'm trying to test this out using curl (I've tried both from localhost and remotely, the result is the same).

If I curl the path over http, it works great.  If I do it over https, the request looks like garbage (see below) and curl returns "curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received."

Requests received over https typically looks similar to:

```
136.152.142.32 - - [16/Nov/2017 01:32:56] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x16\x03\x01\x00\xe3\x01\x00\x00\xdf\x03\x03Z\x0c\xea\xcf\rG\x12,\xea}\xc4\x17n\xb7\x0c\x0b\xea\xdbM\x87n\xf3\x95\xa7(\x15+\xb5lyzY\x00\x00n\x00\xff\xc0,\xc0+\xc0$\xc0#\xc0')
136.152.142.32 - - [16/Nov/2017 01:32:56] "??Z
G,?}?n?           

                        ??
```

I added SSL functionality by simply adding an ssl_context to my flask app.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    context = ('fullcert.pem', 'privkey.pem')
    app.run(debug=False, ssl_context=context)
```

The keys are signed by a CA and worked fine in a comparable node application (I'm trying to convert that node application over to python/flask).

I've tried basically reinstalling from the ground up with no success.

This is being hosted on DigitalOcean in case anyone knows of some weird default configuration that they do that could be causing this.  I've specifically opened the port that the application is running on.

Does anyone have any other suggestions of what could be causing the problem?

Comment: "*If I curl the path over http*" you shouldn't be able to do that if you've correctly setup your certificates. From your log, it looks like Flask is listening as a plain HTTP server and isn't using TLS at all (which is why `curl`'s HTTPS request makes no sense to it). What does running your application with `debug=True` produce?

Comment: I thought about that, I had seen some posts that seemed to indicate that this could be caused by some kind of conflict between an HTTP and HTTPS server running on the same port, but I haven't found any fix.

Comment: Running with debug=True gives essentially the same garbage output.

Comment: Update: it gives me the same output if I remove everything related to SSL.  It basically seems to be not even attempting to use SSL.

Comment: Does Flask print out "*Running on https://...*" when you start it up? Does a completely minimal 10-line Flask app exhibit the same problem?

Comment: No, it says "Running on http://..."  I didn't catch that until now.  The flask app I'm running now isn't much more than a completely minimal 10-line flask app, but I'll try a completely minimal version.

Comment: I've just attempted with the 10-line flask app, the only change I made from the bare minimum was adding the ssl_context.  Works for http, garbage for https.

Comment: Can you post the exact code you're using for the minimal app? Flask prints out "*Running on https://*" if you pass *anything* into `ssl_context`, from what I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and chalk this up to some kind of problem with the Flask dev server.  I deployed my application using the exact same code with Apache (specifically, I followed this handy guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps) and it worked.